# twitter not returing to app after sign in android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

Hello im using auto with twitter.

My code worked pretty well until i changed my access from "Read only" to "Read and Write".

My problem is that after clicking on "Sign In" on the web page its not coming back to my app.

I read about it and i know that its about the callback URL.

Here is my code:

```
static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "oauth://t4jsample";


private void loginToTwitter() 
        {
            // Check if already logged in

                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
                Configuration configuration = builder.build();

                TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
                twitter = factory.getInstance();

                try {
                    requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);

                    this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));

                } catch (TwitterException e) {

                    Toast.makeText(OpeningPage.this, "Something went wrong, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}
```

My manifest:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="t4jsample"
            android:scheme="oauth" />
    </intent-filter>
```

My twitter settings page:

[image]

Thank for helping

Comment: Check out twitter integration here which will guide you. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

in your case you need display in application, not external browser app, use WebView in Android, after create custom web client like:

```
private class CustomWebClient extends WebViewClient {
...

 @Override
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

 } 

}
```

and set to your WebView:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebClient());
```

in method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` you need track your callback url.

Comment: If you use external browser, you can't track browser redirects, but if use internal browser, like above, you can track all your urls, in method **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** you need add if query, like
**if(url.equals(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {}**

but no to use:

this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));

Comment: use, look above in his code, method: private void loginToTwitter()